# Is there a way to use react-redux (useDispatch) in react using class based components? I am using useDispatch inside render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are intended to be used in Functional components only. As per the [Rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) they can be called from

- React function components.
- Custom Hooks

In order to other question

> Is there a way to use react-redux (useDispatch) in react using class based components?

Yes, there are ways of using react-redux inside class based components. Using [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect) API provided by `react-redux` library which will inject the action creators into the class component. Eventually accessing the required `dispatch` function by `this.props`. You can have a look [here](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial#connecting-the-components) for a basic example of how it can be used.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hooks with class components. As written in the [docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components), you need to create a container/wrapper component that passes the actions.

For that you have to use `connect` from 'react-redux' like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: id => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(mapStateToProps (HERE NOT NEEDED; IF YOU WANT TO DISPATCH ONLY), mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList)

export default VisibleTodoList
```

This would pass `onTodoClick` to your component via props which you can just call like any prop: `this.props.onTodoClick()`